# maven: Go online after going offline for remote development

Tags: maven

```
$ mvn dependency:go-offline
```

caches all the dependencies for offline/remote development. It is documented at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html

But, how do we go back online again?

```
$  mvn dependency:go-online
```

is not a valid goal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check `dependency:go-offline` [goal's documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) .

In the description it states:

> Goal that **resolves** all project dependencies, including plugins and
>   reports and their dependencies.

Emphasis mine.

This goal just tells Maven to resolve everything this project is dependent on (dependencies, plugins, reports) in **preparation** for going offline. So it just fetches locally all required stuff and nothing more.

Offline mode is enabled only when you provide the `-o` flag on a appropriate command ex. `mvn -o install` and for the scope of this command **only**.

In the above command, if `-o` is specified, maven will not check online for updates of dependencies,plugins etc and will try to retrieve them from the local repository. That's why you have to execute the aforesaid goal of maven dependency plugin before, in order everything to be available for offline mode.